# Comparing two binary numbers with a limited set of operators in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm currently writing code in assembly for a simple computer and I've got to find a compare two binary number two each other and check whether the second number is smaller or equal to the first number.

I've got the following instruction set available:

```
Halt, Stop : stops machine.
ldacc <variable/constant>: loads something into the ACC
Stac <variable> : save data from ACC into a variable
Movacc : moves data from ACC into R
Jmp <label>: jpm to label
jmpz <label>: conditional jump, jumps when z=1, (z=1 when acc = 0)
out : outputs ACC data to OUTR register
Sub: acc-r stores in acc
Add: acc-r stores in acc
inc: increment acc value by 1
clacc: clears acc
and: binary and operation on acc and r, stores in acc
or : binary or operation on acc and r, stores in acc
ashr: bit shift right on data in acc (0010->0001) == div2
not: not operation on acc
```

So I'm trying to create a do while loop and at the end of every iteration I want to check wether number2 =< number 1, if so acc=0 and z=1 and we jump to another label.

Comment: Do you want do to signed or unsigned comparison?

Comment: If `x - y` doesn't overflow, you can look at the sign bit (e.g. with `ashr` to copy the sign bit down to all other bits, leaving 0 or -1) for isgned comparison.  But if you have to handle overflow, that's harder without some kind of ALU flags output.

Answer (score 2):

This answer applies to relational comparison for data interpreted as signed:

- Subtract them
- If they are equal, you'll have zero for the subtraction result, so you know they are equal
- Otherwise

  - If they are both positive<sup>1</sup>, or, if they are both negative<sup>2</sup> then

    - If the subtraction result is negative, then

      - The former (minuend) was less than the latter (subtrahend)
    - Otherwise

      - The former was greater than the latter
  - Otherwise: one is positive and one is negative, so

    - The negative number is smaller than the positive number

<sup>1</sup> extract their signs each with `ashr`, `add` their extracted signs, test the addition for zero ⇔ they are both positive

<sup>2</sup> `and` them together, extract the result's sign, test the extracted sign for non-zero ⇔ they are both negative

*An xor operation would have been a simpler way to test both signs being the same, but your RSC (Relatively Simple CPU) doesn't have it.*

---

`ashr` in the above to be used in sufficient shift quantity to make the number entirely 0 for positive numbers or -1 for negative numbers, as per @PeterCordes comment.

---

If you know that they are both positive signed numbers, this is much simpler, as you can eliminate most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

3 bit math works just as well as 30 bit as well as 32 bit as well as 96 bit...

```
operand a - operand b = result.  
Z (zero flag) 
C (carry out/unsigned overflow)
V (signed overflow)
N (negative)

011 - 000 = 1011 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 001 = 1010 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 010 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 011 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 100 = 0111 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 101 = 0110 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 110 = 0101 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 111 = 0100 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
```

Addition and subtraction logic that uses twos complement for signed numbers only requires one adder to do those operations, there isn't a special signed addition/subtraction nor unsigned addition/subtraction, the beauty of twos complement (that is the RESULT works with that logic in either case).  But for unsigned vs signed comparisons then the other typical flags are needed.  Your logic doesn't have these but when I post the *ad-hoc* program used to print the above, you will see I synthesized these things using only and and equal or not equal.

```
011 - 000 = 1011 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 001 = 1010 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 010 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 011 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 100 = 0111 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 101 = 0110 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 110 = 0101 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 111 = 0100 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
```

so if we view this first as unsigned 3 - 0, 3 - 1, 3 - 2 and so on to 3 - 7.

If you think through what you were taught from grade school to the present

a - b = a + (-b).

twos complement a number invert and add one so

a - b = a + (~b) + 1

we use an adder to subtract and invert the second operand and the carry in (of the lsbit).

```
 1000
- 999
=====
```

we have to "borrow" from the next column over.

The carry flag plays a big role in our lives, from the first years of grade school to the present, it is also known as the unsigned overflow flag and the borrow flag.

When we treat the adder as a sub tractor the carry out is the inverse of a borrow, if a borrow happened meaning say for example 000 - 999 in decimal which we didn't do that way in school but if we did for the hundreds digits we would be borrowing from the thousands digit and there would be this borrow hanging out there in the wind but 456 - 123 wouldn't have a borrow hanging out there in the wind.

```
011 - 000 = 1011 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 001 = 1010 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 010 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 011 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
011 - 100 = 0111 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 101 = 0110 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 110 = 0101 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
011 - 111 = 0100 Z0 C0 V1 N0 0
```

The carry flag changes from 0 to one at the point where unsigned b is greater than unsigned a.  4>3 but 3 = 3 and less carry is 0 so

a - b, c = 0 unsigned less than or equal   a <= b
a - b, c = 1 unsigned greater than         a > b

So you can do a C and Z test to check for the or equal or just reverse operands, which reverses the equation at the end of the line

b - a, c = 0 unsigned greater than or equal   a >= b
b - a, c = 1 unsigned less than               a < b

You don't need to use the z flag just order your operands right depending on whether you want the or equal or not and which size direction you want.

The C flag which is also the inverse borrow indicated that we either didn't borrow or did for those subtractions and whether we did or not indicated the second operand was greater than or not.

That is for UNSIGNED!

For signed...

```
010 - 000 = 1010 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
010 - 001 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
010 - 010 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
010 - 011 = 0111 Z0 C0 V0 N0 1

001 - 000 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
001 - 001 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
001 - 010 = 0111 Z0 C0 V0 N0 1
001 - 011 = 0110 Z0 C0 V0 N0 1
```

no doubt the signed overflow flag matters, but also signed has to do with positive or negative so does the nflag matter too?

Knowing the answer that big hanging out at the end is an N == V comparison.

Notice as a - b changes from b going less than a we get n == v. when a < b

```
110 - 100 = 1010 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
110 - 101 = 1001 Z0 C1 V0 N1 0
110 - 110 = 1000 Z1 C1 V0 N1 0
110 - 111 = 0111 Z0 C0 V0 N0 1
```

Yes for the positive numbers the C flag works too but in general for signed we want one rule.  And for negative numbers   -2 compared to -4,-3,-2,-1 n == v indicates a < b.

So n!=v would indicate a>=b.  if you reverse the operands on the subtraction then b-a n==v would indicate a > b and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void doit ( unsigned int ra, unsigned int rb )
{
    unsigned int rc,rd,re;
    unsigned int cflag,vflag,zflag,nflag,vxflag;

    rc = ra + ((~rb)&7) + 1;
    re = (ra&3) + ((~rb)&3) + 1;
    cflag = (rc>>3)&1;
    vflag=0;
    if(((ra&4)==((~rb)&4))&&(((~rb)&4)!=(rc&4))) vflag=1;
    vxflag=0;
    if(((re>>2)&1)!=cflag) vxflag=1;
    zflag=0;
    if((rc&7)==0) zflag=1;
    nflag=0;
    if((rc&4)==0) nflag=1;
    for(rd=4;rd;rd>>=1) if(ra&rd) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    printf(" - ");
    for(rd=4;rd;rd>>=1) if(rb&rd) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    printf(" = ");
    for(rd=8;rd;rd>>=1) if(rc&rd) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    printf(" Z%u",zflag);
    printf(" C%u",cflag);
//    printf(" V%u%u",vflag,vxflag);
    printf(" V%u",vflag);
    if(vflag!=vxflag) printf("!!");
    printf(" N%u",nflag);
    if(nflag==vflag) printf(" 1"); else printf(" 0");
    printf("\n");
}
int main ( void )
{
    doit(3,0);
    doit(3,1);
    doit(3,2);
    doit(3,3);
    doit(3,4);
    doit(3,5);
    doit(3,6);
    doit(3,7);

    doit(2,0);
    doit(2,1);
    doit(2,2);
    doit(2,3);

    doit(1,0);
    doit(1,1);
    doit(1,2);
    doit(1,3);

    doit(6,0);
    doit(6,1);
    doit(6,2);
    doit(6,3);
    doit(6,4);
    doit(6,5);
    doit(6,6);
    doit(6,7);
    return(0);
}
```

So the quick and dirty program to create the 3 bit output.

Your homework would be to know how the flags are generated and how to use them.

From grade school we know

```
 89
+11
====
```

can also be done as result, carry = 9+1 = 0,1 and 8+1+carry = 8+1+1 = 10 overall result 100 decimal  but done in parts.

Why do it in parts, so that I can see the carry.  If I wanted to do an 8 bit addition (which subtraction is addition in binary) I could do that as two 4 bit additions and the fifth bit in the low order bits is my carry out.

```
  z   w
   xxxx xxxx
   yyyy yyyy
=============
```

So why would I do that? if I only had 8 bit registers, I would cut it up in some way so that the upper bit operation done with 8 bit registers gives me 4 bits of result and I can "see" the msbit carry out, the carry flag.  As I did in the c code, did 3 bit math with much greater than 3 bit variables, so I can see the carry bit.

All of this is doable with the instructions you have available.  Nothing shown here is secret or magic, can be found at Wikipedia or elsewhere, other processor documentation, etc. elementary alu stuff, but not necessarily presented in this way (other than the several other times I did this here and other folks).